# How to make an excel formula that creates a line break in a cell without using wrap text

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can anyone help me Write an Excel formula that creates a line break without using the wrap text button, as i need to import the cells into an external program with a line break already applied?

Comment: https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/excel-insert-a-line-break-in-a-cell/ this link might be help you. Please check

Comment: I have already tried to used this method and it doesn't work for the application i need. Is there another method? Thanks

Comment: not sure exactly how you wish to achieve what you are after but CHAR(10) will give you a line break and can be used with in a formula,ie. ="text"&CHAR(10)&"text"

Comment: What User91504 said. You can use CHAR(10) or CHAR(13).

Comment: All comments seem to miss the point of applying "line break". The solution might be to run a script (VBA or Python using Win32 API) to perform this. Depends on the use case (and in particular how the initial file is generated).